# Sorting issue using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

This is my html

```
<div class="products-grid">
    <div data-sort="3" class="swiper-slide">Test</div>
    <div data-sort="1" class="swiper-slide">Test</div>
    <div data-sort="2" class="swiper-slide">Test</div>
</div>
```

and this is js that i tried:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    function getSorted(selector, attrName) {
        return jQuery(jQuery(selector).toArray().sort(function(a, b){
            var aVal = parseInt(a.getAttribute(attrName)),
                bVal = parseInt(b.getAttribute(attrName));
            return aVal - bVal;
        }));
    }
    getSorted('.products-grid .swiper-slide', 'data-sort');
});
```

It doesn't working. I want to sort it after the data-sort attribute. Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Unwrap your `getSorted` return value from `jQuery()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add sorted elements to DOM

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  function getSorted(selector, attrName) {
    return jQuery(selector).toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
      var aVal = parseInt(a.getAttribute(attrName)),
        bVal = parseInt(b.getAttribute(attrName));
      return aVal - bVal;
    });
  }

  var sortedElements = getSorted('.products-grid .swiper-slide', 'data-sort');
  jQuery('.products-grid').append(sortedElements);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="products-grid">
  <div data-sort="3" class="swiper-slide">Test 3</div>
  <div data-sort="1" class="swiper-slide">Test 1</div>
  <div data-sort="2" class="swiper-slide">Test 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are sorting array of elements, but not the elements in DOM

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   function getSorted(selector, attrName) {
      return jQuery(jQuery(selector).toArray().sort(function(a, b){
          var aVal = parseInt(a.getAttribute(attrName)),
              bVal = parseInt(b.getAttribute(attrName));
        
          return aVal - bVal;
      }));
  }
  $('.products-grid').html( getSorted('.products-grid .swiper-slide', 'data-sort')  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="products-grid">
   <div data-sort="3" class="swiper-slide">Test 3</div>
   <div data-sort="1" class="swiper-slide">Test 1</div>
   <div data-sort="2" class="swiper-slide">Test 2</div>
</div>
```